# How to properly send a Signal with an initial value using ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa, frp

I'm trying to send a Signal from one ViewModel to another one. Basically I want the second ViewModel to use the same Signal as the first ViewModel, but I also need the initial value at init state in the second ViewModel . So far I have manage to solve this by sending the `Signal<Person, NoError>` and the `Person` model.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

In `PersonListViewModel` the Signal is defined as output where the stream is handled.

```
protocol PersonListViewModelOutputs {
     var goToPersonDetail: Signal<Person, NoError> { get }
}
```

`PersonDetailViewModel`:

```
protocol PersonDetailViewModelInputs {
    func viewDidLoad()
    func configureWith(personSignal: Signal<Person, NoError>, initialPerson: Person)
}

protocol PersonDetailViewModelOutputs {
    var person: Signal<Person, NoError> { get }
}

protocol PersonDetailViewModelType {
    var inputs: PersonDetailViewModelInputs { get }
    var outputs: PersonDetailViewModelOutputs { get }
}


public final class PersonDetailViewModel: PersonDetailViewModelType, PersonDetailViewModelInputs, PersonDetailViewModelOutputs {

    init(){
        self.person = self.configureWithPersonPropery.signal.skipNil()
    }

    private let configureWithPersonProperty = MutableProperty<Person?>(nil)
    func configureWith(personSignal: Signal<Person, NoError>, initialPerson: Person) {
        configureWithPersonProperty.value = initialPerson
        configureWithPersonProperty <~ personSignal.producer
    }
}
```

However this solution seems to bring unnecessary parameter inside `func configureWith(...)` and I guess there could be a better way to solve it.

For example, is it possible to get the last emitted value from `personSignal: Signal<Person, NoError>` inside `func configureWith(...)` without sending the Person Struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your signal is `NoError`, you can just pass in a `Property` instance instead of a `Signal`. A property is basically a signal that is guaranteed to have a value and can't send an error. You can create one with an initial value and an existing signal:

```
let prop = Property(initial: initialPerson, then: signal)
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!